sbatch failed: the script was read with mistakes
I've created a script which I developed running it and testing it chunk by chunk in R. I then created a .sh file to submit it to HPC.
The script runs alright and output all files needed as results (ie .txt and plots). However, when submitting it via sbatch:
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=run_funct
#SBATCH --output=/[path]/logs/run_funct.out
#SBATCH --error=/[path]/logs/run_funct.err
#SBATCH --ntasks=1
#SBATCH --time=24:00:00
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=8042  
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4
#SBATCH --partition=compute

Rscript /[path]/code/analyse.correlation.R

(where [path] is the full path to read/write in the cluster, omitted here)
Although everything runs OK in an interactive session, when submitting a sbatch job I get the following error:
State: FAILED (exit code 1)
Nodes: 1
Cores per node: 4
CPU Utilized: 00:50:36
CPU Efficiency: 24.89% of 03:23:20 core-walltime
Job Wall-clock time: 00:50:50
Memory Utilized: 3.57 GB
Memory Efficiency: 11.35% of 31.41 GB
note that the original script reads like this:
# write table correlation results
write.table(gene.database, file = file.path(data.dir, paste0(biomarker, "_", lineage, "_correlation_unified.txt")), sep = "\t");


But when reviewing the log file for .err, the following is shown:
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"        gene.database,
        file = file.pte0(biomarker, "_", lineage, "_correlation_unified.txt")),"
Execution halted

This error is thrown after already having run several lines, after finishing a heavy for-loop chunk calculating correlations. The write.table outputs the results of an immediate mapply downstream analysis from that correlation.
I'm afraid there is some mistake in reading the file submitted to slurm, but don't know how to fix this as I can't find the fault.
I've run the script in an interactive shell and everything works to a good end.

Did you check the R script on the line where the error appears? I'm not an expert in R, but it seems to me that it have no relation with the line you show in your question.
Also, did you checked the R script with the same inputs you are using in the submitted job? If not, did you checked that the R script with your test parameters follow all code paths?

Thanks Poshi, yes. All seems fine, the original script does not have a line cropped, I've run the script manually with the parameters input in the .sh file and it arrives to the write table line with no errors.
I think the unexpected ',' is because write.table() arrives to a second closing bracket i.e. after .txt")) because somehow the script gets chopped where the function file.path() should begin...?

Is the same R version installed on the node where you run the interactive tests than in the batch nodes?
